# Problems with jQuery DatePicker setting a second DatePicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

So, I've managed to code this so far.  Whats meant to happen is a user selects the '`arrdate`', then the code automatically sets the endDate of the '`depdate`' to 1 day later.  However, the issue here is that the `'arrdate'` format is `non-US`, ie; `dd/mm/yy`, yet the code that is meant to push it one day later is picking it up as `mm/dd/yy.`

This pushes everything out of whack, eg, selecting today `11/08/2011` in the arrdate sets the depdate to `09/11/2011.`

I've tried several ways to no avail - anyone that can tell me where I can set the format better?  Thanks!

```
$(function() {
    $( "#arrdate" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate: 0 ,
        onSelect: function(date){

            var selectedDate = new Date(date);
            var msecsInADay = 86400000;
            var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);


            $("#depdate").datepicker( "option", "minDate", endDate );
        }
    });
    $( "#depdate" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday. So I had to make a bit of a workaround,
before you start adjusting the date +1day, switch it around:

```
//Convert Date from dd/mm/yy to mm/dd/yy
var iDay = date.substring(0,2);
var iMth = date.substring(3,5);
var iYr =  date.substring(8,11);

var date = iMth+"/"+iDay+"/"+iYr;
var selectedDate = new Date(date);
```

You may have to do something similar to convert it back to dd/mm/yy

Comment: This worked fine!

`onSelect: function(date){
    //Convert Date from dd/mm/yy to mm/dd/yy
    var iDay = date.substring(0,2);
    var iMth = date.substring(3,5);
    var iYr =  date.substring(8,11);

    var date = iMth+"/"+iDay+"/"+iYr;

                var selectedDate = new Date(date);
                var msecsInADay = 86400000;
                var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);
    
                $("#depdate").datepicker( "option", "minDate", endDate );`

Thanks very much!